# Log out user and terminate session by admin in Angular

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I need to have a feature in my Angular application whereby the admin is able to logout and terminate the session of a user who is logged in to the system. My back-end is based on Spring Boot restful API with custom authentication. How can I manually logout the currently logged in user and terminate their session while using Angular?

I have a controller that changes the flag in the 'logged_in' column in the user table in the database. However that does not log out the user nor terminate their session as desired, instead logs out the current user (admin) instead of the other user who is logged in.

My angular code where I am making the API call:

```
    this.apiService.LogUserOut(this.userProfile).subscribe(res => {
            this.blockUI.stop();
            this.response = res;
            // end user session

this.authService.logout(this.userProfile.username).subscribe(data => {});
            this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
            this.globalService.setAuth(false);
            localStorage.removeItem('otc');
 });
```

Controller end-point:

```
// logout a logged-in user
@PostMapping(value = "/sysusers/logUserOut")
public ResponseEntity<?> LogUserOut(@RequestBody User user) throws 
 Exception {
    System.out.println("User logged out: " + user.getUsername());
    userService.SetUserLoggedOut(user.getUsername());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new 
 CustomResponse(CustomResponse.APIV, 201, true, "You have logged the user 
out"), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I expect the system to filter and check if user is logged in such that when admin logs user out, the system is able to notify, otherwise the system should log the user out. I know how to log off current user  but have no idea how to force log out other users, so some help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what about just use SetUserLoggedOut from admin endpoint .. and leave the frontend until next update and returning then a 401

Comment: `SetUserLoggedOut` only changes the logged_in flag in the database but the user still remains logged in.

Comment: what does "logged_in" mean in that context? the frontend still show "logged in"?

Comment: `logged_in` is the column in the users table that has a boolean flag that shows whether user is logged in or not.

Comment: i understand that ... so why not setting the flag to false from admin endpoint? next action on frontend get a 401 as response and the gui could show the logged out screen .. thats how it works with a web frontend ... if you want so send the logged of info the frontend, the webpage eighter has to poll some loggedinstatus or you have to use websockets ..